# Want to use C# code inside C++ code

Tags: c#, c++

I have written code for chat application in C#. Now I want to use that code inside C++ code. Please guide me in this regards.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

You can (in decreasing order of practicality):

- Expose a COM interface from your C# library and consume the COM object in your C++ application
- Use C++/CLI to directly talk to your C# library
- [Host the CLR yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x0wh2z3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in your C++ application to instantiate and communicate with the library
- [Embed Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) into your C++ application

Comment: Important to note to those options probably get exponentially harder as you head down the list...

Answer (score 0):

If both the c# and the C++ code are compiled in .NET then simply create a class library for C# compile and reference in C++. This is due to the CLR and it all compiling down to MSIL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use C++/CLR, which allows you to mix managed and unmanaged code.